# Floating two elements to the left?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I think I need some more assistance with the concept of floating. This time my question revolves around floating two or more elements to the left. How does this work exactly? I know that a float lifts the children of the element off the page and moves them all the way to the left. All other elements respond by wrapping around... but how does the concept of floating two elements apply to this?

Here is what I understand: Say I have two DIVs, a and b. Float a to left, b's content will wrap around it... but if I float b to the left... How does the content respond to a?

**EDIT:** Here is something I was messing around with to see if I could understand this concept.

[image]

The first DIV has an inline style that floats it to the left... But see how the second DIV with no inline style margin is all wacky?... It doesn't show this wacky margin when the DIV is floated to the left also.

**Edit:** I know inline styles are bad... I was just using them to showcase an example here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a series of very comprehensive tutorials: [Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/). By following the tutorials it becomes very clear how floating works.

To answer your specific question: When you have two elements with `float:left`, then the surrounding content will wrap the second element, then the first if there's room left.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ak736

Comment: I have looked at that tutorial numerous times but it did not give me a good explanation of how floating two elements to the left or right works. Don't get me wrong though, that is a great tutorial.

Comment: Have you looked at it or did you actually work through the tutorials? If not then I highly recommend taking the time. This will probably answer all your questions and give you confidence in applying the concept.

Comment: Yes I took my time through them. I understand how floating works in general... I'm just looking for a good explanation on how floating two elements the same direction works?

Comment: I added a short explanation and a jsFiddle example

Comment: So its like #b knows #a is there and I will check that link out. I added some more details in an edit of what I'm trying to understand about this concept. Look at the wacky margin specifically?

Comment: I think I understand what it actually does... The box model of the DIV with no inline style stretches to hold the other DIV that is floated left.

Comment: @W3Geek Yes, or stated slightly differently: The right divs float around their respective left divs. b floats around a, and c (the one without styling) floats around b and a.